# CGO undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'

Tags: c, windows, go, cgo, lib

I am mostly working on Go projects atm, but I have to use CGO for part of my project on the purpose of editing TIF files from Go with C, because of parameter pass-through. I am not familiar with C, but it seems the only way to solve our problem.

The problem is when I theoretically set up the Go part, and wanted to use my C code, it drops `undefined reference to` xxxx'` with TIFFGetField,_TIFFmalloc,TIFFReadRGBAImage function calls.

Probably I am not even importing the libtiff libary in the right way.
The funny thing is the first code of the C code itself is `TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("foo.tif", "w");` does not have reference error to TIFFOpen, only the others (TIFFGetField,_TIFFmalloc,TIFFReadRGBAImage,_TIFFfree,TIFFClose)

my go code is

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -Ilibs/libtiff/libtiff
// #include "tiffeditor.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.tiffEdit()
}
```

```
#include "tiffeditor.h"
#include "tiffio.h"

void tiffEdit(){
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("foo.tif", "w");
    if (tif) {
        uint32 w, h;
        size_t npixels;
        uint32* raster;

        TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &w);
        TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &h);
        npixels = w * h;
        raster = (uint32*) _TIFFmalloc(npixels * sizeof (uint32));
        if (raster != NULL) {
            if (TIFFReadRGBAImage(tif, w, h, raster, 0)) {
            //
            }
            _TIFFfree(raster);
        }
        TIFFClose(tif);
    }
}
```

My goal on first is just to establish libtiff with my go code and make it to recognise the functions libtiff, so I can focus on solving the problem itself.

Comment: I have removed all other code to be sure TIFFOpen does not have reference error, but it has..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the message "undefined reference to xxx" in cgo. It is very likely that you're missing the linking to the shared library.

I'm not quite familiar to this package, but i suggest you could try add something as below to make your program link to the C dynamic library:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lyour-lib
```

In case above, i link my go program to a C dynamic library called "libyour-lib.so".

### Example

Assumed that your TIFF source comes from http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/

### Steps

1. Download the source codes
2. Check README.md (or INSTALL) to read the guide about how to compile this C library
3. Follows provided instructions and install the C library
4. If you're doing correctly without modifying default settings, you should find tiff headers in /usr/local/include and its dynamic libraries in /usr/local/lib
5. Integrates these stuffs to your go program by having proper hints for cgo compiler.

### Codes

I've build this program successfully, and executed as expected. It might be a good starting point for you.

```golang
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ltiff
// #include "tiffio.h"
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    path, perm := "foo.tif", "w"

    // Convert Go string to C char array. It will do malloc in C,
    // You must free these string if it no longer in use.
    cpath := C.CString(path)
    cperm := C.CString(perm)

    // Defer free the memory allocated by C.
    defer func() {
        C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cpath))
        C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cperm))
    }()

    tif := C.TIFFOpen(cpath, cperm)
    if tif == nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("cannot open %s", path))
    }

    C.TIFFClose(tif)
}
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for trying to help my dumbass ^^ 
It seems it does not have .so or .a files in it, only code and header files, could it be a problem?

Comment: the program does not say atm it does not find the file (as the libtiff says, to include tiffio.h), it just shows undefined reference to `functionName`

Comment: @Stephen Yes, what you said is totally correct. It did find the header file (tiffio.h) which provides only definition to the C functions that your going to use. The problem is the compiler cannot find its implementation, which is covered by some C library generated from tiffio.

Comment: You have to compile the tiffio first, then link your program with necessary tiffio libraries. If you're in UNIX like system, use "ls /usr/local/lib" to check if there are some files with prefix "libtiff". These objects are the shared libraries that you have to link with in your go program.

Comment: @Stephen you might want to check the edited answer. Hope this can help.

Comment: thank you very much, yes, it was the problem, however my C experienced collegue will continue the work with this, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Butcan I use a libary if I have the code with header and code files without compiling it seperately, or just compiling it with my own code? I mean I have a directory with my code, and a libtiff subdirectory with for example this libtifff codes, with all of the tiff C files (.h .c), and I want to "include" it.

Comment: @Stephen it is possible to do that. But in practical, many complicated C programs are quite hard to build compared to go. That's why most of the cgo users prefer to do the way as i described above.